# Multiple ARSCNViews with different nodes in one screen

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I want to show two different 3D objects in two different ARSCNViews.
With [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691179/arkit-stereo-is-it-possible-to-run-two-arscnview-at-the-same-time) it's allowed to show the two ARSCNViews, but it is basically cloned one view to another.

I want to display different objects in each view.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You can create two ARSCNViews with different models, or even a RealityKit view and an ARKit view. However, in both cases you have to use the same [running ARSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59463704/is-it-possible-to-have-arview-and-arscnview-coexist/71184502#71184502). It is not possible to run two different sessions in parallel.

```
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    @IBOutlet var sceneViewTwo: ARSCNView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sceneViewTwo.session = sceneView.session
        
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
        sceneView.scene = scene
        
        let sceneTwo = SCNScene()
        sceneViewTwo.scene = sceneTwo
        
        let sphere = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.1))
        sphere.position.z = -1.0
        sceneViewTwo.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere)
        
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(config)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your code, and it worked for me as well. But if I try to implement two ARSCNView, it didn't work(no error, but a black screen is shown)

Comment: Yesss! It helped me a lot what i want to do! Thanks! :)